# select all string between single quotes using vim

Tags: vim

I have the following text:

```
select region_id, 'Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years' as category, Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years as number from income_mf_pivot 
union
select region_id, 'Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_20_24_years' as category, Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_20_24_years as number from income_mf_pivot
union
select region_id, 'Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_25_34_years' as category, Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_25_34_years as number from income_mf_pivot
union
select region_id, 'Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_35_44_years' as category, Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_35_44_years as number from income_mf_pivot
```

What I would like to finish up with (I presume via a selection) is

```
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_20_24_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_25_34_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_35_44_years
```

I thought it would be something like /g to do the selection (using it to select everything between the two '), then somehow yank that, but I have run out of steam.

I am not a vim purist.  I don't mind if it is more than one command.  I am after this to be able to be run on a whole document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `yi'` command allows to you yank the text between the single quotes, but that only works for a single instance at a time.

As long as the width is identical (i.e. you have a rectangular selection), you can use *blockwise visual mode*, started with `<C-v>` (often `<C-q>` on Windows).

To get all text within single quotes, you can use my [ExtractMatches plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4795). It provides the following command:

```
:%YankMatchesToReg /'\zs[^']\+\ze'/
```

After that, you can just `p`aste the text and add the trailing commas. If all matches should be in one single line, the `g,p` from my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355) can do that in one swoop.

Comment: While I didn't use your plugin directly, I found [vim-yankitute](https://github.com/someboddy/vim-yankitute) through your plugin page, and I was more familiar with how to install it.  The regex was the same though, which matched exactly what I was after, thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could place the cursor on the first M, then start block visual mode with `CTRL-v`, move to the other end of what you want to yank with `6je` and yank it with `y`.
This does yank the empty lines though, but they should be easy to get rid of once pasted.

Another way, which would also append the commas is to use an external filter like `sed`:

```
:r!sed -n "s/.*'\(Males[^']*\).*/\1,/p" %
```

This results in

```
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_20_24_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_25_34_years,
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_35_44_years,
```

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that there are exactly two single quotes in each target line, as in your example text.

I would select the desired lines in Visual mode, then enter Ex mode with <kbd>:</kbd>.  The range `'<,'>' (representing the Visual selection) will be inserted automatically.  I would complete that to

```
:'<,'>v/'.*'/d
```

(remove all lines that do not contain two <kbd>'</kbd> characters) to get rid of the "union" lines.  Then <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> to re-select the Visual selection, and complete the command line to

```
:'<,'>s/^[^']*'\|'.*//g
:'<,'>-s/$/,
```

or maybe, instead of those two commands,

```
:'<,'>s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1,
```

and then remove the <kbd>,</kbd> from the last line.

Answer (score 1):

To select

```
Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years
```

from

```
select region_id, 'Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years' as category, Males_Negative_Nil_income_Age_15_19_years as number from income_mf_pivot
```

Use `vi'` (select inner single quotes)

Do `:help object-select` to read about it